# How to print out / access the content of a const void pointer?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, void-pointers

I am trying to use this example:

```
std::size_t s2 = boost::asio::buffer_size(buffer);
const void* p2 = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const void*>(buffer);
```

And I am getting a vaild size `s2` and some seemingly valid address `p2`.

Now, how could I create a `cout` or `printf` loop or phrase a debug-statement, to see the content of `p2`?

I bet this is quite basic, but currently I can't see what I am missing.

Tried this:

```
std::cout << "TEST: " << boost::asio::buffer_cast<const void*>(buffer) << std::endl;
```

but it only prints out the address, not the content

and this:

```
for(int i =0; i!=s2; i++){
    std::cout << "TEST: " << p2[i];
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

but I am ending up with compile errors, like C0253 - unknown size.

So, how can I print out the content of `p2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can print the bytes pointed to by buffer as:

```
std::size_t s2 = boost::asio::buffer_size(buffer);
const void* p2 = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const void*>(buffer);

unsigned char const* bytes = static_cast<unsigned char const*>(p2);
for(std::size_t i = 0 ; i < s2 ; ++i)
     std::cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(bytes[i]);
```

Of course, you have to interpret the output.

You can print the hexadecimal values instead which is easier to interpret:

```
std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned int>(bytes[i]);
          // ^^^^^^^^ note this
```

I think you have to `#include<iomanip>` for this.

Comment: just perfect! hex-print out is exactly what I want, you nailed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The content of p2 is a memory address...since p2 is a pointer.

A void* means that the language + libraries are not aware of the type of data being referenced.
You can't print the value being pointed to if you don't know of what type it is.

Comment: yeah, unless you cast it to a type.